# submenu in one line with css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

[image: sample]

I want to make navigation menu like the picture above with hover on Menu. This is my sample code for the navigation menu.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu1
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Menu1Sub1</li>
        <li>Menu1Sub2</li>
        <li>Menu1Sub3</li>
        <li>Menu1Sub4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu2
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Menu2Sub1</li>
        <li>Menu2Sub2</li>
        <li>Menu2Sub3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Submenu position are in a line and I also want Submenu position to be exactly same for each Menu if possible.

How to do this with css?

this is what I tried so far not working as I intended.

```
#menu { 
        text-decoration:none;
}
#menu li { 
        line-height:20px; 
        float:left;
}
#menu li > ul { 
        display: none; 
}
#menu li:hover > ul { 
        display: block;
} 
#menu li ul li {
        line-height:13px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: @Guillaume added my css so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
#menu { 
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
        text-decoration:none;
}

#menu li { 
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height:30px; 
    float:left;
}

#menu li > ul { 
    display: none; 
}

#menu > ul > li {
    border: 2px solid white;
}

#menu > ul > li:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#menu li:hover > ul { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 0;
}

#menu li ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

[DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/jLm1qs14/)

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect now.